# Any iOS Device build errors after WebRTC's XCFramework update

Tags: ios, webrtc, armv7, xcframework

I'm getting errors after I have updated to XCFramework of WebRTC. Here's manual instruction of it: https://swiftpackageregistry.com/alexpiezo/WebRTC

```
...missing required architecture armv7...
```

I don't need for Mac, so my steps like that:

```
gn gen ./out/ios_arm64 --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64" is_component_build=false is_debug=false ios_deployment_target="10.0" rtc_libvpx_build_vp9=true use_goma=false ios_enable_code_signing=false enable_stripping=true enable_ios_bitcode=false'

gn gen out/ios_x64 --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="x64" is_component_build=false is_debug=false ios_deployment_target="10.0" rtc_libvpx_build_vp9=true use_goma=false ios_enable_code_signing=false enable_stripping=true enable_ios_bitcode=false'

ninja -C out/ios_arm64 sdk:framework_objc
ninja -C out/ios_x64 sdk:framework_objc

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework ./out/ios_arm64/WebRTC.framework \
    -framework ./out/ios_x64/WebRTC.framework \
    -output ./out/WebRTC.xcframework
```

It's working on iOS Simulators and real devices but Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7) does not work.

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCMediaConstraints
Undefined symbol: _kRTCMediaStreamTrackKindVideo
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCAudioSessionConfiguration
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCAudioSession
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCIceCandidate
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCIceServer
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCConfiguration
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCCallbackLogger
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCPeerConnectionFactory
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCDispatcher
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCSessionDescription
Undefined symbol: _RTCSetMinDebugLogLevel
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCRtpTransceiverInit
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCCameraVideoCapturer
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RTCEAGLVideoView
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCEAGLVideoView
```

Is there any advice what should I do to overcome it?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm experiencing the same issue at the moment.

Comment: @Dean did you try latest Xcode version? It should be only arm64 as far as I remember.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following as an argument to `gn gen`:

```
--args='target_os="ios" ios_enable_code_signing=false use_xcode_clang=true is_component_build=false rtc_include_tests=false is_debug=false target_cpu="arm64" ios_deployment_target="10.0" rtc_libvpx_build_vp9=false enable_ios_bitcode=false use_goma=false rtc_enable_symbol_export=true enable_dsyms=true enable_stripping=true'
```

The key here is the `rtc_enable_symbol_export=true` argument.